# Huawei ME906s-158 not working with Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: huawei

I'm working on an HP machine with Ubuntu 16.04 installed and kernel 4.10.0-42-generic #46~16.04.1-Ubuntu. I want to use a Huawei ME906s-158 to connect to a mobile network, which is unfortunately mostly not working.

If I plug in the device, I can sometimes use it as expected with the graphical network manager tool. But after a few minutes (mostly after only a few seconds) the connection suddenly disappears without any error message. The network manager shows the device under wired connections as Ethernet Network and disconnected, and it is grayed-out.
Often it is not detected as mobile broadband device at all and is shown as wired connection as described before.

I googled a lot but found no solution, which is why I try to get your help here. Please tell me which information you need to help me, these are things I tried:

i) This is the output of "dmesg" when no connection is established

```
[10396.949204] usb 3-13.1: new high-speed USB device number 11 using xhci_hcd
[10397.050249] usb 3-13.1: New USB device found, idVendor=12d1, idProduct=15c1
[10397.050253] usb 3-13.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[10397.050255] usb 3-13.1: Product: HUAWEI Mobile
[10397.050256] usb 3-13.1: Manufacturer: Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd.
[10397.050258] usb 3-13.1: SerialNumber: 0123456789ABCDEF
[10397.053658] cdc_ether 3-13.1:2.0 usb0: register 'cdc_ether' at usb-0000:00:14.0-13.1, CDC Ethernet Device, 02:1e:10:1f:00:00
[10397.054034] option 3-13.1:2.2: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
[10397.054182] usb 3-13.1: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB0
[10397.054423] option 3-13.1:2.3: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
[10397.054564] usb 3-13.1: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB1
[10397.054772] option 3-13.1:2.4: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
[10397.054905] usb 3-13.1: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB2
[10397.055098] option 3-13.1:2.5: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
[10397.055220] usb 3-13.1: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB3
[10397.055427] option 3-13.1:2.6: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
[10397.055559] usb 3-13.1: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB4
[10397.089063] cdc_ether 3-13.1:2.0 enp0s20u13u1c2: renamed from usb0
[10397.139964] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp0s20u13u1c2: link is not ready
[10397.140197] cdc_ether 3-13.1:2.0 enp0s20u13u1c2: kevent 12 may have been dropped
[10397.145814] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp0s20u13u1c2: link is not ready
[10413.066889] usb 3-13.1: USB disconnect, device number 11
[10413.066968] cdc_ether 3-13.1:2.0 enp0s20u13u1c2: unregister 'cdc_ether' usb-0000:00:14.0-13.1, CDC Ethernet Device
[10413.089680] option1 ttyUSB0: GSM modem (1-port) converter now disconnected from ttyUSB0
[10413.089692] option 3-13.1:2.2: device disconnected
[10413.089816] option1 ttyUSB1: GSM modem (1-port) converter now disconnected from ttyUSB1
[10413.089822] option 3-13.1:2.3: device disconnected
[10413.089926] option1 ttyUSB2: GSM modem (1-port) converter now disconnected from ttyUSB2
[10413.089935] option 3-13.1:2.4: device disconnected
[10413.090035] option1 ttyUSB3: GSM modem (1-port) converter now disconnected from ttyUSB3
[10413.090043] option 3-13.1:2.5: device disconnected
[10413.090175] option1 ttyUSB4: GSM modem (1-port) converter now disconnected from ttyUSB4
[10413.090182] option 3-13.1:2.6: device disconnected
```

Always if the connection could be established for short time, dmesg shows:

```
[10981.483608] usb 3-13.1: new high-speed USB device number 39 using xhci_hcd
[10981.584906] usb 3-13.1: New USB device found, idVendor=12d1, idProduct=15c1
[10981.584909] usb 3-13.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[10981.584911] usb 3-13.1: Product: HUAWEI Mobile
[10981.584913] usb 3-13.1: Manufacturer: Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd.
[10981.584914] usb 3-13.1: SerialNumber: xxx
[10981.588332] cdc_ether 3-13.1:2.0 usb0: register 'cdc_ether' at usb-0000:00:14.0-13.1, CDC Ethernet Device, 02:1e:10:1f:00:00
[10981.588725] option 3-13.1:2.2: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
[10981.588837] usb 3-13.1: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB0
[10981.589089] option 3-13.1:2.3: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
[10981.589202] usb 3-13.1: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB1
[10981.589417] option 3-13.1:2.4: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
[10981.589505] usb 3-13.1: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB2
[10981.589703] option 3-13.1:2.5: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
[10981.589784] usb 3-13.1: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB3
[10981.589992] option 3-13.1:2.6: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
[10981.590075] usb 3-13.1: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB4
[10981.632588] cdc_ether 3-13.1:2.0 enp0s20u13u1c2: renamed from usb0
[10981.675707] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp0s20u13u1c2: link is not ready
[10981.675926] cdc_ether 3-13.1:2.0 enp0s20u13u1c2: kevent 12 may have been dropped
[10981.680673] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp0s20u13u1c2: link is not ready
[11012.270567] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): enp0s20u13u1c2: link becomes ready
[11012.270577] cdc_ether 3-13.1:2.0 enp0s20u13u1c2: kevent 12 may have been dropped
[11012.275779] cdc_ether 3-13.1:2.0 enp0s20u13u1c2: kevent 12 may have been dropped
```

ii) "lsusb -v" shows:

```
Bus 003 Device 018: ID 12d1:15c1 Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. 
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.10
  bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level)
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol       255 
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x12d1 Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd.
  idProduct          0x15c1 
  bcdDevice            1.02
  iManufacturer           1 Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd.
  iProduct                2 HUAWEI Mobile
  iSerial                 3 xxx
  bNumConfigurations      3
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength          301
    bNumInterfaces          6
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0xa0
      (Bus Powered)
      Remote Wakeup
    MaxPower                2mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           3
      bInterfaceClass       255 Vendor Specific Class
      bInterfaceSubClass      6 
      bInterfaceProtocol     16 
      iInterface              7 Huawei Mobile Connect - Modem
      ** UNRECOGNIZED:  05 24 00 10 01
      ** UNRECOGNIZED:  04 24 02 02
      ** UNRECOGNIZED:  05 24 01 00 00
      ** UNRECOGNIZED:  05 24 06 00 00
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x82  EP 2 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x000a  1x 10 bytes
        bInterval               9
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x01  EP 1 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        1
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           2
      bInterfaceClass       255 Vendor Specific Class
      bInterfaceSubClass      6 
      bInterfaceProtocol     19 
      iInterface              8 Huawei Mobile Connect - Application
      ** UNRECOGNIZED:  05 24 00 10 01
      ** UNRECOGNIZED:  04 24 02 02
      ** UNRECOGNIZED:  05 24 01 00 01
      ** UNRECOGNIZED:  05 24 06 00 00
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x83  EP 3 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x02  EP 2 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
    ... (do you need the full information, it has more than max. allowed characters?)
```

iii) "usb-devices" shows:

```
T:  Bus=03 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=08 Cnt=03 Dev#= 44 Spd=480 MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.10 Cls=00(>ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=ff MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  3
P:  Vendor=12d1 ProdID=15c1 Rev=01.02
S:  Manufacturer=Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd.
S:  Product=HUAWEI Mobile
S:  SerialNumber=xxx
C:  #Ifs= 7 Cfg#= 2 Atr=a0 MxPwr=2mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=02(commc) Sub=06 Prot=00 Driver=cdc_ether
I:  If#= 1 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=0a(data ) Sub=06 Prot=00 Driver=cdc_ether
I:  If#= 2 Alt= 0 #EPs= 3 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=06 Prot=10 Driver=option
I:  If#= 3 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=06 Prot=13 Driver=option
I:  If#= 4 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=06 Prot=12 Driver=option
I:  If#= 5 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=06 Prot=14 Driver=option
I:  If#= 6 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=06 Prot=1b Driver=option
```

Interestingly the device is sometimes not listed in usb-devices and lsusb.

iv) "mmcli -L" shows

```
No modems were found
```

or if a connection is possible:

```
Found 1 modems:
    /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Modem/16 [Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd.] ME906s-158
```

If a modem is detected I can use "sudo mmcli -m xx" (here xx=16), showing:

```
/org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Modem/17 (device id '8f2c1ff8885e6c1f5b123a3b7382aa49353c683c')
  -------------------------
  Hardware |   manufacturer: 'Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd.'
           |          model: 'ME906s-158'
           |       revision: '11.617.04.00.00'
           |      supported: 'gsm-umts'
           |        current: 'gsm-umts'
           |   equipment id: '867160025875216'
  -------------------------
  System   |         device: '/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-10'
           |        drivers: 'option1, cdc_ether'
           |         plugin: 'Huawei'
           |   primary port: 'ttyUSB0'
           |          ports: 'ttyUSB0 (at), enp0s20u10c2 (net), ttyUSB2 (at), ttyUSB3 (at)'
  -------------------------
  Numbers  |           own : 'unknown'
  -------------------------
  Status   |           lock: 'none'
           | unlock retries: 'sim-pin (3), sim-pin2 (3), sim-puk (10), sim-puk2 (10)'
           |          state: 'connected'
           |    power state: 'on'
           |    access tech: 'lte'
           | signal quality: '48' (recent)
  -------------------------
  Modes    |      supported: 'allowed: 4g; preferred: none
           |                  allowed: 3g; preferred: none
           |                  allowed: 2g; preferred: none
           |                  allowed: 2g, 3g, 4g; preferred: none'
           |        current: 'allowed: 2g, 3g, 4g; preferred: none'
  -------------------------
  Bands    |      supported: 'unknown'
           |        current: 'unknown'
  -------------------------
  IP       |      supported: 'ipv4'
  -------------------------
  3GPP     |           imei: 'xxx'
           |  enabled locks: 'none'
           |    operator id: 'xxx'
           |  operator name: 'xxx xx'
           |   subscription: 'unknown'
           |   registration: 'home'
  -------------------------
  SIM      |           path: '/org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/SIM/10'

  -------------------------
  Bearers  |          paths: '/org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Bearer/8'
```

v) The behavior seemed to occur suddenly. I bought these modules about a month ago and tried them to check whether they are defective or OK, and I can't remember that I experienced similar behavior. It then occured yesterday after the cards where stored in my cupboard.

vi) I tried to setup udev rules, as it is recommended in several forums. I installed usb_modeswitch in version

```
usb_modeswitch: handle USB devices with multiple modes
 * Version 2.5.0 (C) Josua Dietze 2017
 * Based on libusb1/libusbx
```

and added

```
ATTR{idVendor}=="12d1", ATTR{idProduct}=="15c1", RUN+="usb_modeswitch -v 0x12d1 -p 0x15c1 -u 3"
```

to the "40-usb_modeswitch.rules" file in the beginning, but it did not help.

vii) If I try "usb_modeswitch -v 0x12d1 -p 0x15c1 -u 3" in the console it shows:

```
Look for default devices ...
   product ID matched
Get the current device configuration ...
 Found devices in default mode (1)
Access device 120 on bus 003
Get the current device configuration ...
Current configuration number is 2
Use interface number 0
 with class 2

USB description data (for identification)
-------------------------
Manufacturer: Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd.
     Product: HUAWEI Mobile
  Serial No.: xxx
-------------------------
Change configuration to 3 ...
 Device is busy, try to detach kernel driver
Looking for active driver ...
 OK, driver detached
 Device is busy, try to detach kernel driver
Looking for active driver ...
 No active driver found. Detached before or never attached
 Device is busy, try to detach kernel driver
Looking for active driver ...
 No active driver found. Detached before or never attached
 Device is busy, try to detach kernel driver
Looking for active driver ...
 No active driver found. Detached before or never attached
 Changing the configuration failed (error -6). Try to continue
-> Run lsusb to note any changes. Bye!
```

viii) I'm not bound to the network-manager, and tried to setup the connections in its files directly, but the same behavior occured. Until now I did not install other software to setup the my connection. Should I give it a try? Can't I do it without installing another tons of libaries?

ix) This strange behavior occurs with three devices of the same type and three SIM-cards, also of the same type and provider. I also tried to get the modem working on two more computers, one (near) fresh Ubuntu 16.04 installation and one Ubuntu 17 installation. The behavior is the same on both. Until now I did not test with SIM cards of other providers, I will try to do so as soon as possible.

Is there anybody who can help or knows the problem? Thank you very much for your help.
Martin

Comment: Hi, please tell me is there nobody who can help with my problem or did I do something wrong with my question? Can I provide other, more, less, different information to help anybody helping me or did I do something completely wrong?
Thank you very much.

Comment: Just to help others with similar problems. I could finally test with a SIM card of another net provider. The problems seemed to be disappeared, the stick could be used about two hours without any problems.

Due to the fact that the electromagnetic field is weak at my buro I assume that the module has problems with the reconnection, which then leads to the described problems. But since the problem seems to be correlated with the network itself I think this thread can be closed.